# Dynamic tab navigation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've developed a hybrid application based on Ionic.
Now we have a new client that requires the same functionalities but, since I can't sell him the same app, I need to change my app's L&F.

The states are loaded dinamically based on a service's response. It works just fine, but with my team we've decided to change from a side menu to tabs navigation and here's the problem.

We'd love to leave the state definition and html as it is right now, so, in a future, if a new customer comes, we can parameterize the application without any need to change HTML, just some javascript flags.

Anyway, here´s the dynamic state definition:

```
.state('menu.generico', {
                url: "/trans/:capp/:cmod/:ctr",
                resolve: { 
                     someResolve: function($stateParams,$ionicHistory,$q, CashModals){
                },
                views: {
                    'menu-generico': {
                        templateProvider: function(){
                        }
                     }
                 }
            });
```

Besides, I have a directive that's in charge of creating the menu.
I tell it if I want a sidebar menu or tabs navigation.
Anyways, the tabs structure it returns is something like:

```
<cargar-menu-mobile>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-bar-container" nav-bar-transition="ios" nav-bar-direction="back" nav-swipe="">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="hide" data-ng-click="myGoBack()"></ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right" class="hide"></ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">
            <ion-tab title="Posición" icon="ion-card" ui-sref="menu.generico" ng-click="tabChanged(1)">
                <ion-nav-view name="menu-generico" cache-view="false"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>
    </ion-nav-bar>
</cargar-menu-mobile>
```

So, when I start navigating the app the navigation looses it's thread. By this, I mean that if i navigate a while inside the tab's view, then press the first tab (menu-generico), finally I get the back button activated but I don't want it activated, since the tab is the root state.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if You dont want back button then,

```
<ion-nav-back-button class="hide" data-ng-click="myGoBack()"></ion-nav-back-button>
```

remove this line. Ionic maintains separate history for tab views. Go through following thread to know more about it,

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keep-main-header-bar-disable-back-button-on/19868

Comment: The thing is that sub states of all tabs go through menu.generico. So, if I go to a tab that belongs to menu.generico I get a back button, when it's supposed to be a root tab. Am I explaining? It's not that I don't want a back button at all

Comment: I need a way to kinda "reset" the navigation flow

Comment: you can get the index of root tab from
`var index = $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex();`
and if it's 0 then disable back button as

`$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I finally added these lines to the tabChanged function on my directive:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
      historyRoot: true
});
```

So, this way, each tab is the root.

Now I just have to recognize to wich tab each state belongs, in order to activate it's corresponding tab.

Hope someone find's it useful.